# Save Arduino UNO Serial Data every (X) minutes

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I have a basic sketch in Arduino sending data every second via serial and visualized with Processing 2.1.

**From Arduino**

```
"Serial.println();  // after all the sensors have been read print a newline     and carriage return
  delay(1000);  // delay by # milliseconds"
```

**In Processing:**

```
Serial myPort; 
PrintWriter output; //print serial output from Arduino
void setup() { 
size(480, 360); 

output = createWriter( "saved-serial-data.txt" ); //save file as ""
println(Serial.list());  
myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411", 9600);
myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
} 

void draw() { 
output.println(inString);
}
```

I was able to get the file to save but it's empty because I don't know how to initiate the trigger to save and record the data based on time. I have seen examples based on keypress (for ex: void keyPressed() { // Press a key to save the data) however my sketch just loops and there are no keypresses needed. I'd like it to save every 5 minutes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer then in `draw()` check if 5 minutes elapsed. If so then `flush()` and `close()` your output. I believe you might have to recreate the output after it has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you know how to populate `inString`, although you haven't posted the code that does that.

But assuming that, there are a couple ways to set up a timer.

You could use the [`millis()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/millis_.html) function. This function returns the number of milliseconds your program has been running, so you can use it to record start and end times, and then use those times to calculate the elapsed time. If the elapsed time is over some threshold, then you can fire your event. Something like this:

```
int prevFiredTime = 0;
int msDelay = 10000; //10 seconds

void draw(){
   int time = millis();
   int elapsed = time - prevFiredTime;
   if(elapsed > msDelay){
      fire();
      prevFiredTime = time;
   }
}

void fire(){
   output.println(inString);
}
```

You could also use the [`frameCount`](https://www.processing.org/reference/frameCount.html) function. It's similar to the `millis()` function, only it holds the number of frames that have been drawn since the start of the program. You can use it to do something every X frames, like this:

```
int frameDelay = 600; //10 seconds

void draw(){
   if(frameCount % frameDelay == 0){
      fire();
   }
}

void fire(){
   output.println(inString);
}
```

You might have to tinker a bit to get the exact behavior you want, but these are the basic approaches to setting up a timer in Processing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This looks like what I needed. I couldn't find a clearly explained version. Much appreciated.